# 'toString().contains()' method unable to detect '˚' (degree symbol) inside a CharSequence

Tags: java, android, if-statement, symbols, charsequence

I have a `CharSequence` which contains two `˚` (degree) symbol inside it.

I have written an `if` statement which detects what's inside this `CharSequence` like this:

```
CharSequence name = "27°46'29.6"N 77°19'05.9"E";

if (name.toString().contains("˚") {
     Log.d("log", "˚ detected");
} else {
     Log.d("log", "˚ not detected");
}
```

**The problem** is that here `˚ detected` is supposed to be printed out by the log statements, but what is getting printed out is `˚ not detected`.

**Why** the `˚` is not getting detected?

Comment: What did your debugger show as the value of `name` after calling `toString()` on it?

Comment: any reason why you're not just using a string for `name`?

Comment: Does this compile? It looks like you have four quotes in your string literal, perhaps that's just SO's markdown script changing some UTF characters.

Comment: doesn't look like it's the same character at all: `°˚` -> close as typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking 2 different characters, code point 176 vs 730

```
if (name.toString().contains("°")) {
```

Comment: how to make this symbol from MacBook Air's keyboard?

Comment: Just copy the symbol from the CharSequence and paste inside the `contains`

Comment: @Hugo indeed copy or Option + 0176

Comment: @Andreas ok extended ASCII then :)

Comment: *"[Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)"*? Which one? Did you mean **Unicode**, perhaps?